# Attribute returns null in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

My `data-postid` attribute is 'null' when shown in the console. What will be reason for that?

I want to show the `data-id` in the console when clicking the button with modal-save id.

I can not see a mistake

---

### Dashboard

```html
<article class="post hentry video" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">

  <div class="post__author author vcard inline-items">
    <img src="/vendor/img/avatar7-sm.jpg" alt="author">

    <div class="author-date">
      <a class="h6 post__author-name fn" href="#">{{$post->user->firstname}} {{$post->user->surname}}</a> ({{$post->user->username}})
      <div class="post__date">
        <time class="published" datetime="2004-07-24T18:18">
         {{$post->created_at}}
        </time>
      </div>
    </div>
    @if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
    <div class="more"><svg class="olymp-three-dots-icon"><use xlink:href="/vendor/icons/icons.svg#olymp-three-dots-icon"></use></svg>
      <ul class="more-dropdown">

        <li>
          <a href="#">Favorilere Ekle(Yapım Aşamasında)</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="{{ route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}">Sil</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    @endif()
  </div>

  <div class="interaction post-additional-info inline-items">

    <p style="width: 100%">{{$post->body }}</p>

    <a href="#" class="post-add-icon inline-items">
      <svg class="olymp-heart-icon"><use xlink:href="/vendor/icons/icons.svg#olymp-heart-icon"></use></svg>
      <span>18</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="post-add-icon inline-items">
      <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i>
      <span>5</span>
    </a>
    <div class="gon">

      @if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
      <button type="button" class="edit but-oni btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                        Düzenle
                                    </button>
      <a href="{{ route('post.delete', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}" class="but-oni btn btn-primary">
                                        SİL
                                    </a> @endif
    </div>
    <div class="comments-shared">
      <a href="#" class="post-add-icon inline-items">
        <svg class="olymp-speech-balloon-icon"><use xlink:href="/vendor/icons/icons.svg#olymp-speech-balloon-icon"></use></svg>

        <span>2</span>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</article>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Gönderiyi Düzenle</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="">
          <div class="form-group with-icon label-floating is-empty">
            <label class="ex-label control-label" for="post-body">Gönderiyi Düzenleyin</label>
            <textarea class="ex-text form-control" name="post" id="post-body" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-save">Değişiklikleri Kaydet</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<script>
  var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
  var url = ' {{route('
  edit ')}}';
</script>
```

---

### JS

```js
var postId = 0;

$('.post').find('.interaction').find('.edit').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var postBody = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent;
  postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
  $('#post-body').val(postBody);
  $('#exampleModal').modal();
});

$('#modal-save').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: {
        body: $('#post-body').val(),
        postId: postId,
        _token: token
      }
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
      console.log(msg['message']);
    });
});
```

---

### Route

```html
Route::post('/edit', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){ return response()->json(['message' => $request['postId']]); })->name('edit');
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here too. The issue should be in the jquery script.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this code:

```
postId = $(this).closest("[data-postid]").data().postid;
```

It worked for me perfectly.